# How do companies send emails to 1000s and 1000s of people at once?

Tags: php, email

I was wondering how do companies / organisations send emails to so many people at once.

How do they get all those people's email addresses?

How do companies send regular emails to people, do they do it manually or is there is automatic system that does it for them? e.g. I have signed up for an Amazon account and on a daily bases I get 3-5 emails from them about their products and recommendations for me. How does this work?

How does sign up for a news letter on website work?

Thanks for any information, I have searched online and had no luck with finding decent information, it might be my wording of the questions are not correct or their might be some specific keywords that I am missing out from my querys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send same email to 1000 people or more with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956707/send-same-email-to-1000-people-or-more-with-php)

Comment: @RC. this post is not a duplicate of the post you provided, I have asked something completely different to that of the link you have given. Having a PHP tag on my post does not necessary mean that it will be a duplicates of with similar title and a PHP tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure your question belongs on this site, but I'm going to try to answer it anyway.

A spammer will harvest and steal and guess email addresses from anywhere they can. (spider bots, db hacks and dictionary attacks)

A legitimate company will have a contact form or newsletter sign up form that includes an input field for an email address.

The spammers will likely have access to hacked servers and route the spam through their victims.

The legitimate companies will run their email through a system that controls the rate at which they are processed. The really large companies (like Amazon) will have multiple servers that can handle the load.

Comment: hi, what would be the best place to ask this question? btw thanks for your answer.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question in your comment, but the reasoning behind my first sentence is _Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do._ (From the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page.)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are plenty of websites out there that do it for you e.g. http://www.campaignmonitor.com/  and http://www.aweber.com/ which also provide the sign up to newsletters interface.

Answer (score 1):

very broad question, but anyway. acquiring e-mail adresses heavily depends on the type bussiness. offline acivities, newsletter signups etc...

sending mail is mostly accomplished through dedicated services like for example mailchimp or campaign monitor as managing your own infrastructure for this kind of activity is rather demanding.